# How to delete 10% of rows in a data.frame by type in R

Tags: r, dplyr

sorry for my english i'm from russia.
I am starting to learn R and am stuck with one problem, please help.
I have a sorted data.frame in ascending V3 column and descending V4 column.
Data is compiled from many files into one.
I need to remove or filter the first 10% strings for each type (day) while maintaining the sorting.
My data

```
library(gdata)
     myfiles <- list.files("G:/YA_3D/119_211124", pattern = ".txt", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
        myfiles1 <- lapply(myfiles, read_csv)%>% plyr::rbind.fill(myfiles1)
        write.fwf(myfiles1,file="G:/DD_1-125_cor.x",sep="\t", quote=F, rownames=T)
        TILER <- read.table("G:/DD_1-125_cor.x", fill = TRUE, skip = 1)
    TILER$V1 <- sequence(rle(as.character(TILER$V3))$lengths)
```

And before this manipulation I have this data.frame (reduced the number of lines до 8):

```
V1      V2      V3      V4
1       hg      2410    96
2       hg      2410    92
3       hg      2410    91
1       hg      2411    98
2       hg      2411    95
1       hg      2501    36
2       hg      2501    30
```

Then I count the number for each type, divide the resulting value by 100 and multiply by 10 (an attempt to use column V1 to use ifelse to delete all rows less than the value in the new table)

```
TILER1 <- TILER %>% select(V3, V4)

V3      V4
2410    96
2410    92
2410    91
2411    98
2411    95
2501    36
2501    30
```

before

```
TILER.Prod_A <- desc_statby(TILER1, measure.var = "V4", grps = "V3") %>% mutate(YYY3 = ifelse(length >2000, 1, 2)) %>% 
      filter(YYY3 == "1") %>% mutate(Proz = round(length/100)*10) %>% select(V3, length, Proz)
```

And before this manipulation I have new data.frame (value in Proz for example, in real value >1000 because many lines:

```
V3      length  Proz
2410    3       0.3
2411    2       0.2
2501    2       0.2
```

Lastly, I am trying to apply an ifelse statement from one table to the data of another

```
TILER3 <- TILER %>% mutate(T1 = ifelse(V3 == TILER.Prod_A$V3 & V1 < TILER.Prod_A$Proz, "1", "2")) %>% filter(T1 == 2)
```

But ifelse don't work like I want for tis situation, i can't filter T1, because value in T1 not correct.
Maybe someone has other thoughts on how I can do what is needed.

Comment: Please provide example data `dput(myData)` and provide expected output for that example data.

Comment: I think you need to group by type, then remove by rownumber. Try this example: `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% filter(row_number() < 5)` We are grouping by "cyl", then dropping first 4 rows based on row number.

Comment: @zx8754 add file Mydata (what I have) and file Myrez (What I want have). The sorting does not change, I want exactly the first 10% of each value in column V3, not random ones. [link](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/LihB/7MMHjaR1P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem in the following way. Without cycles

```
      TILER <- TILER %>% group_by(V3) %>% 
          mutate(m = max(V4)) %>%
          ungroup()
        
    TILERFIN <- TILER %>% mutate(FIN = (V4*100)/m) %>%
 filter(FIN >= 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve. But if I interpret the headline correctly, you want to eliminate 10% of the rows of a dataframe with various conditions. Here are some ideas.

If you want to select first 10% of rows having a certain value in e.g. attribute V3

```
V3_2410 <- TILER1[TILER1$V3 == 2410, ]  # data frame containing only V3==2410
N <- nrow(V3_2410)  # number of rows in V3_2410 
N10 <- as.integer(0.1*N)  # 10% thereof
idx <- 1:N10  # sequence of row numbers 1, 2, ..., N10
V3_2410_F <- V3_2410 [index, ]  # V3_2410_F has got first 10% of rows
```

If you want to remove these first 10% from TILER1:

```
V3_2410 <- TILER1[TILER1$V3 == 2410, ]  # data frame containing only V3==2410
V3_2410_C <- TILER1[TILER1$V3 != 2410, ]  # compleemnt thereof
N <- nrow(V3_2410)  # number of rows in V3_2410 
N10 <- as.integer(0.1*N)  # 10% thereof
idx <- 1:N10  # sequence of row numbers 1, 2, ..., N10
V3_2410_F <- V3_2410 [-index, ]  # V3_2410_F has got first 10% of rows removed
TILER2 <- rbind(V3_2410_C, V3_2410_F)  # TILER2 has got first 10% of rows with V3==2410 removed
```

and so on.

If you have many values for attribute V3 and you need to address the first 10% of every level, you can do it in a loop like this:

```
V3_values = levels(as.factor(TILER1$V3))  # contains all possible values for V3
for(val in V3_values){
  V3_val <- TILER1[TILER1$V3 == val, ]  # data frame containing only V3==val
  N <- nrow(V3_val)  # number of rows in V3_val
  N10 <- as.integer(0.1*N)  # 10% thereof
  index = 1:N10
  V3_val_F <- V3_val[-index, ]  # first 10% removed
  # and so on
}
```

Comment: I apologize if I did not understand the problem.
I need to delete 10% of the rows, but not randomly, but keeping the sorting by column V3 and V4, respectively, if I have 100,000 rows, then I need to delete 10,000 rows, but column V3 has different days, for example 2410 and 2411 (let's call them so) and the deletion must be done within each day and in order and not randomly. That is, delete the first 10% of lines inside 2410, then go to 2411 and delete the first 10% as well. Not on the total number of rows in the table, but on the number of rows within a day.

Comment: Please see link with 2 file what I have right now (mydata)  and what I want have (myrez) [link](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/LihB/7MMHjaR1P)

Comment: If I have very more attribute V3 (not only one or two, for example 19875 attribute in V3), this is problem work

Comment: I added a solution with `for` loop that can handle many values for V3. I wanted to point you to the principles of filtering and removing rows. The details for your required solution need more work.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't use loops "for" at all, so your method won't work for me, but thank you, you tried.

Comment: This was for demonstration. If speed is required use `apply()`.